# Win32API Printing with Python & GSPrint not working

Tags: python, node.js, pdf, printing

I've been trying to print a PDF document created with Reportlab through the Win32API module and GSPrint.

Using the command line works like a breeze but when I am using `Win32API.ShellExecute()` nothing seems to be printing.

Here is the code I invoke on PDF creation; the `filename = tempfile.mktemp(".pdf")` is used for temp pdf creation.

```
hInstance = win32api.ShellExecute(
  0,
  "open",
  "gsprint.exe",
  '-printer "HP LaserJet 3055 PCL6 Class Driver" ' + filename,
  ".",
  0
)
print filename
```

A handleInstanceID is also return which is 42, but nothing goes to the printer.

The setup is such that JSON data is passed using NodeJS to Python using STDIN and I have used the `python-shell` module. When the python script receives a JSON doc it creates a PDF using ReportLab in a temp file then invokes ShellExecute which in returns the hInstance code back to NodeJS.

Some light on this would be really helpful.

**NodeJS App is running as a Windows Service using node-windows**

NodeJS Script

```
app.post('/printKot', function (req, res) {

    var scriptP = path.join(process.cwd(), 'myPythonScripts', 'demo.py');

    //res.json({path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'myPythonScripts')});

    var pyshell = new PythonShell('printKot.py', {scriptPath: "C:\\\\Users\\\\Sid\\\\posistFineDine\\\\myPythonScripts" });

    // sends a message to the Python script via stdin 
    //pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(req.body.billYoData));
    var kotData = '{"billdata":{"Tp":"Rooftop Table","TN":10,"KN":11,"BN":"12","BD":"2015-06-17T15:09:58.439Z","Name":"","Add":"","St":"","Cy":"","Sta":"","Pin":"","PNm":"","MNm":"","Waiter":"Waiter Sid Gomez","DAmt":0,"Ft":"","WU":false},"billitemsdata":[{"N":"Chilli Bites Potato","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""},{"N":"Chicken Ninja ","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""},{"N":"Chilli Bites Ckn","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""}],"billtaxesdata":[{"N":null,"A":0}],"subtotal":0,"totalTax":0,"roundOff":0,"grandTotal":0,"totalQuantity":3,"iskot":true,"printername":null,"copies":2,"printertype":null}'

    pyshell.send(kotData);

    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
        //console.log(message);
        console.log("Printed");
        res.json({msg: message});
    });

    pyshell.end(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    console.log("Printed last")

    //res.json({msg:true});*/

});
```

Python Script

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, cm, letter
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle 
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT
from reportlab.lib import colors

import json
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print
import sys
import base64
import os
import subprocess



#jsonData = sys.stdin


#kotObject ='{"billdata":{"Tp":"Table","TN":14,"KN":6,"BN":"16","BD":"2015-06-12T12:57:11.844Z","Name":"","Add":"","St":"","Cy":"","Sta":"","Pin":"","PNm":"","MNm":"","Waiter":"Waiter Sid Gomez","DAmt":0,"Ft":"","WU":false},"billitemsdata":[{"N":"Chow Manchow Chicken","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""},{"N":"Double Corn Chicken","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""},{"N":"Double Corn Veg","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""},{"N":"Whopping Wonton Soup Veg ","Q":1,"R":0,"W":0,"U":""}],"billtaxesdata":[{"N":null,"A":0}],"subtotal":0,"totalTax":0,"roundOff":0,"grandTotal":0,"iskot":true,"totalQuantity": 0, "printername":null,"copies":2,"printertype":null}'


bill = json.load(sys.stdin)
#bill = json.loads(kotObject)


filename = tempfile.mktemp(".pdf")

itemLen = len(bill['billitemsdata'])
taxLen = len(bill['billtaxesdata'])

width, height = A4
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='HeaderFooter', fontName ='Helvetica',fontSize=10, alignment=TA_CENTER))

styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='RightAlignedValueAmount', fontName ='Helvetica',fontSize=10, alignment=TA_RIGHT))

styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Details', fontName ='Helvetica', fontSize=10, alignment=TA_CENTER))

styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='LeftAligned', fontName='Helvetica', fontSize=10, alignment=TA_LEFT))


def coord(x, y, unit=1):
    x, y = x * unit, height -  y * unit
    return x, y


hItem = Paragraph('''<b>Items</b>''', styles["LeftAligned"])
hQty = Paragraph('''<b>Qty</b>''', styles["RightAlignedValueAmount"])
hRate = Paragraph('''<b>Qty</b>''', styles["RightAlignedValueAmount"])


data = []

data.append([Paragraph('Type: <b>%s</b>' % bill['billdata']['Tp'], styles["LeftAligned"]), '', ''])
data.append([Paragraph('KOT Number: <b>%s</b>' % bill['billdata']['KN'], styles["LeftAligned"]), '', ''])
data.append([Paragraph('Bill Number: <b>%s</b>' % bill['billdata']['BN'], styles["LeftAligned"])])
data.append([Paragraph('Date: <b>%s</b>' % bill['billdata']['BD'], styles["LeftAligned"])])
data.append([hItem, '', hQty])


for item in bill['billitemsdata']:
    data.append([Paragraph('%s' % item['N'], styles["LeftAligned"]), '', Paragraph('%s' % item['Q'], styles["RightAlignedValueAmount"])])


data.append(['','',''])

data.append([Paragraph('<b>Total Qty:</b>', styles["LeftAligned"]), '', Paragraph('%s' % bill['totalQuantity'], styles["RightAlignedValueAmount"])])


table = Table(data, colWidths=[5 * cm, 1 * cm, 2 * cm])

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                        ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'MIDDLE'),
                        ('SPAN', (0,0),(2,0)),
                        ('SPAN',(0,1), (2,1)),
                        ('SPAN',(0,2), (2,2)),
                        ('SPAN',(0,3), (2,3)),
                        ("LINEBELOW", (0, 3), (-1, 3), 1, colors.black, None, (1,2,3)),
                        ("LINEBELOW", (0, 4), (-1, 4), 1, colors.black, None, (2,2,4)),
                        #('SPAN', (0,-1), (2,-1)),
                        #('SPAN', (0,2), (-1,2)),
                        #("LINEBELOW", (0, 3), (-1, 3), 1, colors.black, None, (1,2,3)),
                        #("LINEBELOW", (0,itemLen+3),(-1,itemLen+3),1, colors.black, None, (1,2,3))
                        #("LINEABOVE", (0, -1), (2, -1), 1, colors.black),
                        #("LINEBELOW", (0, -1), (2, -1), 1, colors.black),
                        #('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.blue),
                        #('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.red)
                       ]))


c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=A4)
#c.line(10,0,10,height)
#c.setFont('Helvetica', 12)
#c.drawString(10,840-cm,"Welcome to Reportlab!")

#print "Width %s" % width
#print "Height %s" % height
#print "CM %s" % cm

w, h = table.wrap(0, 0)

#print "Table Width %s" % w
#print "Table Height %s" % h

table.wrapOn(c, width, height)
table.drawOn(c, 10, height-(h+cm+80))
c.save()


# if sys.version_info >= (3,):
#   raw_data = bytes ("This is a test", "utf-8")
# else:
#   raw_data = "This is a test"

# printer_name = 'HP LaserJet 3055 PCL6 Class Driver'
# hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter (printer_name)
# try:
#   hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
#   try:
#     win32print.StartPagePrinter (hPrinter)
#     win32print.WritePrinter (hPrinter, raw_data)
#     win32print.EndPagePrinter (hPrinter)
#   finally:
#     win32print.EndDocPrinter (hPrinter)
# finally:
#   win32print.ClosePrinter (hPrinter)

 hInstance = win32api.ShellExecute(
   0,
   "open",
   "gsprint",
   '-printer "HP LaserJet 3055 PCL6 Class Driver" ' + '"%s"' % filename,
   ".",
   0
 )
 print filename
```

Comment: Try to put filename in quotes `'"%s"' % filename`.

Comment: @Delimitry I've tried that, it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried `os.system('gsprint.exe -printer "HP LaserJet 3055 PCL6 Class Driver" "filename"')`?

Comment: Or `win32api.WinExec` instead of `win32api.ShellExecute`?

Comment: @Delimitry No I haven't, let me try and update. Thanks.

Comment: @Delimitry I've tried these still no success.

Comment: Try without printer - just `os.system('gsprint.exe "filename"')`

Comment: @Delimitry You mean something like this `os.system('gsprint.exe "%s"' % filename)`

Comment: Yes, have you checked it?

Comment: @Delimitry Yes I've checked it, but still nothing. Looks like shellExecute fails silently and I can't figure why.